# SqlAlchemy association tables resulting with duplicate records

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many

Given the following schema

```
class Header(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'header'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Row(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'row'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    header_id = Column(Integer)

    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary="row_tag", back_populates="rows")

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    rows = relationship("Row", secondary="row_tag", back_populates="tags")

class RowTag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'row_tag'
    row_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('row.id'), primary_key=True)
    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True)
```

When I commit a Header object that has tags attached to its rows, each row is duplicated by the number of its attached tags.

I understand that SQLAlchemy interprets this as new records for the association table RowTag, resulting in the duplication of Row records.

How to avoid this duplication in rows, and ensure that SQLAlchemy recognizes the existing tags and doesn't create duplicates?

**Simplified example of my application**

DB and Imports

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class MySQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    """A custom SQLAlchemy class to handle multiple databases sessions."""


db = MySQLAlchemy()
Model = db.Model
```

Schema

```
class Header(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'header'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Row(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'row'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    header_id = Column(Integer)

    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary="row_tag", back_populates="rows")


class Tag(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    rows = relationship("Row", secondary="row_tag", back_populates="tags")


class RowTag(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'row_tag'
    row_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('row.id'), primary_key=True)
    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True)
```

Functions

```
def insert_rows(header_id, tags):
    """
        Simplified version of inserting rows function,
        more rows attributes come with the request, instead of doing a dummy loop.
    """
    ready_rows = []
    for i in range(3):
        row1 = Row({"id": i, "header_id": header_id})
        row1.tags.extend(tags)

        ready_rows.append(row1)

        # If I uncomment this line here, rows are inserted without any duplication and each has 2 tags attached in the association table
        # session.add(row1)
        # session.flush()

    return ready_rows


def new_page():
    # Tags are selected from database
    tags = [tag1, tag2]

    # Add header
    header = Header({"id": 1})
    session.add(header)
    session.flush()

    # Add rows
    ready_rows = insert_rows(header.id, tags)

    # I add rows with bulk_save_objects here, and each row is inserted twice (or by the number of tags attached to it)
    session.bulk_save_objects(ready_rows)
    session.flush()   

    # Commit at last
    session.commit()

    return None, 200


# Run
new_page()
```

Comment: I tried the following solution:
committing each row by itself which worked fine, but for optimization, I add everything without commits, then commit once at the end of the request.

Comment: please add a sample of inserting rows.

Comment: I updated my question with a sudo code close enough to my project structure, please refer to the commits, I added notes about my problem there, @hmnFalahi

Comment: Running this code, I get three rows created.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion, the commit is not related to the problem, the `session.add` is, and I updated my question, you can see that I use `session.bulk_save_objects` to insert many rows at once, @snakecharmerb